# XSL to traverse multiple levels of XML and return text output

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have a requirement to traverse an XML input using XSL and return a Pipe-delimited Text output.
So far I have gotten to the halfway mark, I am pretty new to XSL and have gotten only so far.
Below is the XML input (this is only for one Employee and his respective dependents):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA_DS>
<Parent_Group>
    <Employee_Traversal_Record>
        <Employee_1_Child_Group>
            <Employee_1_Detail_Record>
                <Employee_Number>12345</Employee_Number>
                 <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
                <First_Name>John</First_Name>
                <Date_of_Birth>1964-02-28T00:00:00.000Z</Date_of_Birth>
                <Standard_Working_Hours>40</Standard_Working_Hours>
                <Plan_Name>B Plan</Plan_Name>
                <Coverage_Start_Date>2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</Coverage_Start_Date>
                <Plan_Type>B</Plan_Type>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent1</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1998-09-03T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>B Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>B</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                         <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent2</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1960-11-08T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>B Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>B</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent3</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1993-09-09T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>B Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>B</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
            </Employee_1_Detail_Record>
        </Employee_1_Child_Group>
        <Employee_1_Child_Group>
            <Employee_1_Detail_Record>
                <Employee_Number>12345</Employee_Number>
                <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
                <First_Name>John</First_Name>
                <Date_of_Birth>1964-02-28T00:00:00.000Z</Date_of_Birth>
                <Standard_Working_Hours>40</Standard_Working_Hours>
                <Plan_Name>A Plan</Plan_Name>
                <Coverage_Start_Date>2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</Coverage_Start_Date>
                <Plan_Type>A</Plan_Type>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent1</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1998-09-03T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>A Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>A</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent2</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1960-11-08T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>A Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>A</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent3</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1993-09-09T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>A Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>A</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
            </Employee_1_Detail_Record>
        </Employee_1_Child_Group>
        <Employee_1_Child_Group>
            <Employee_1_Detail_Record>
                <Employee_Number>12345</Employee_Number>
                <Last_Name>Doe</Last_Name>
                <First_Name>John</First_Name>
                <Date_of_Birth>1964-02-28T00:00:00.000Z</Date_of_Birth>
                <Standard_Working_Hours>40</Standard_Working_Hours>
                <Plan_Name>C Plan</Plan_Name>
                <Coverage_Start_Date>2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z</Coverage_Start_Date>
                <Plan_Type>C</Plan_Type>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent3</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1993-09-09T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>C Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>C</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent2</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1960-11-08T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>C Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>C</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
                <Dependent_Child_Group>
                    <Dependent_Detail_Record>
                        <Parent_Employee_Number>12345</Parent_Employee_Number>
                        <Dependent_Last_Name>Doe</Dependent_Last_Name>
                        <Dependent_First_Name>Dependent1</Dependent_First_Name>
                        <Dependent_Birth_Date>1998-09-03T00:00:00.000Z</Dependent_Birth_Date>
                        <Relationship_Status>A</Relationship_Status>
                        <Plan_Name>C Plan</Plan_Name>
                        <Plan_Type>C</Plan_Type>
                    </Dependent_Detail_Record>
                </Dependent_Child_Group>
            </Employee_1_Detail_Record>
        </Employee_1_Child_Group>
    </Employee_Traversal_Record>
</Parent_Group>
</DATA_DS>
```

And below is the XSL that I have made as of now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="Employee_Traversal_Record">
    <xsl:copy-of select="Employee_1_Child_Group[1]/Employee_1_Detail_Record[1]/Employee_Number"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Employee_1_Child_Group[1]/Employee_1_Detail_Record[1]/Last_Name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Employee_1_Child_Group[1]/Employee_1_Detail_Record[1]/First_Name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Employee_1_Child_Group/Employee_1_Detail_Record[Plan_Type='A']/Plan_Name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Employee_1_Child_Group/Employee_1_Detail_Record[Plan_Type='B']/Plan_Name"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="Employee_1_Child_Group/Employee_1_Detail_Record[Plan_Type='C']/Plan_Name"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The requirement:

1. Print the Employee details on the First row with the Corresponding Plan Names based on the type in the same row side by side
2. Print the corresponding Employee's dependent details on the following rows with their Corresponding Plan Names based on the type

Current Output:
12345|Doe|John|A Plan|B Plan|C Plan

Expected Output:
12345|Doe|John|A Plan|B Plan|C Plan
12345|Doe|Dependent1|A Plan|B Plan|C Plan
12345|Doe|Dependent2|A Plan|B Plan|C Plan
12345|Doe|Dependent3|A Plan|B Plan|C Plan

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT-1.0 you can traverse all nodes that contain text and output those as a pipe delimited string using `//*`, only looping over those which contain text (`[text()]`). You'll only need one small template:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[text()]">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this does leave a trailing pipe, but that should be an easy fix for you.

See it working here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHT8